# Is there a way to always show Hour:Minute even with phone's language configured in Arabic?

Tags: swift

I have a DatePicker that shows Hour:Minute in my storyboard.

When switching my phone to Arabic language, the control shows Minute:Hour.

Is there a way to always show Hour:Minute no matter what is the language?

What I tried:

- `UIDatePicker.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`
- `timePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")`
- `timePicker.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")`
- `timePicker.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`

UPDATE: 2023-12-19

Here some screenshots of what I meant. The below example is showing 16h00 (4pm). The first one is the LTF and the second one is the RTL. I would like to always have LTF no matter of the phone's language.

Phone's region & language set to Canada-English

[image]

Phone's region & language set to Canada-Arabic

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question with some simple code that demonstrates the issue? Show all details related to creating and setting up the date picker.

Comment: @HangarRash, I added 2 screenshots to help understanding what I meant. The date picker is inside a storyboard. Though, i just tried to create a SwiftUI component that was supposedly be used to replace the iOS one and got the same issue! :-(

Comment: I knew what you meant. I'm asking to see relevant code for setting up the picker. Or if it's in a storyboard, show a screenshot of the picker's properties (and relevant code, if any).